# facebook permission not working in iframe app

Tags: php, facebook

i want to go to next page in an iframe based application in facebook and i want to get permission in that page but permission code didnt work in next page. although working in default index page
here is my code
this work fine in index.php but not working redirect page

```
$app_id = '107919565956374';

$canvas_page = 'http://www.roohware.net/products/mytestapp/';

$auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
. $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);

$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
} else {
echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than

```
echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
```

Try with,

```
echo "<a target='_parent' href='" . $auth_url . "'>Allow application</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
```

with

```
echo '<fb:redirect url="'.$auth_url.'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
        echo "<fb:redirect url={{$auth_url}} />";
```